# Take JTextArea and add entered contents to a label

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout, null-layout-manager

Basically I have a program with cards(I'm using the CardLayout), when the user types a sentance or what ever they type I would like that to be added to a label on the following page when they hit a button named create.
I'm not sure how i would get the entered field to be saved and placed as a variable into the label. any ideas? I can provide my code if necessary.

```
createButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   //Back button listener, switches back to ADMIN fixtures panel
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(container, "6");
                String theText = descriptionField.getText();
                fixtureDescLabel.setText( theText );
                fixtureDescLabel.setBounds(250, 150, 200, 40);
                add(fixtureDescLabel);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward.

Take the text from the textArea:

```
String theText = myTextArea.getText();
```

Put in a label:

```
myLabel.setText( theText );
```

In a button listener:

```
myButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @override public actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        String theText = myTextArea.getText();
        myLabel.setText( theText );
    }
} );
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your edit, your problem is that you add a component to your frame without revalidating (`JFrame#revalidate()`) it.

Comment: I added it but it isn't showing up?

Added code to main question#

Comment: why do you add the jlabel again?

Comment: I applied the string to the label and tthen add that label to the position  `fixtureDescLabel.setBounds(250, 150, 200, 40);` and then I displayed it by using `add(fixtureDescLabel);`

Comment: So your problem is different. After adding components to the frame you need to call JFrame#revalidate. otherwise it will not be updated..

Comment: I'm not sure you understand me. Basically I have to screens, one containing a JTextArea and a button, and the other containing a label. I want the user to enter something into the TextArea and click the button. When the user clicks the button I would like it to add the entered text onto the label.

Comment: In this case, why do you re-add the label?

Comment: It's fine no problem. I fixed it I was adding the component in the wrong place. Many thanks!